# CSSTransition not working with stripe elements React

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a CSSTransition that works until I add the CardElement from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

```
<CSSTransition
          classNames="method"
          in={radio === 'add-card'}
          exit={!(radio === 'add-card')}
          timeout={500}
          unmountOnExit>
          <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="stripe-ad">
            <input
              type="text"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Enter Email Address (Optional)"
            />
            <CardElement id="card-element" options={cardStyle} onChange={handleChange} />
                
            {error && (
              <div className="card-error" role="alert">
                {error}
              </div>
            )}
            <p className={succeeded ? "result-message" : "result-message hidden"}>
              Payment succeeded, see the result in your
              <a
                href={`https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments`}
              >
                {" "}
                Stripe dashboard.
              </a> Refresh the page to pay again.
            </p>
          </form>
        </CSSTransition>
```

When I comment out the , the transition will work properly over the 500ms time interval. When I leave the Card element in, it will refuse to adhere to the transition rules.

I'm using the base cardstyle

```
  const cardStyle = {
    style: {
      base: {
        color: "#32325d",
        fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
        fontSize: "16px",
        "::placeholder": {
          color: "#32325d"
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        color: "#fa755a",
        iconColor: "#fa755a"
      }
    }
  };
```

The problem is that the CardElement either has its own transition on mount, or the style needs to be changed. Has anyone ever had this issue with the stripe element on transition?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this will not work as the Elements exist within a Stripe-hosted iframe. Only certain styles are supported on Elements:
https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/style

I suggest opening an issue on github with a minimal example of this, for example forked from the codesandbox demo.
https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/issues